# Selecting a unique combination without knowing one of the fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have simplified this a bit to frame the question. There are more tables involved but this is the core of the problem:

So I have a table with just 2 columns in it in MSSQL 2008.

```
GroupID   |  Culture
1         |  en-gb
2         |  fr-fr
3         |  en-gb
3         |  fr-fr
4         |  en-gb
4         |  fr-fr
4         |  es-es
```

I have no idea what the Group ID is but I want to be able to do the following:

1) Select en-gb only - returning me the unique row with the GroupId of 1 and NOT the rows with GroupIDs 3 and 4
2) Select en-gb AND fr-fr to give me the GroupID of 3

I did have a look around for any examples of this - but its possible Im not even thinking of the correct search terms. thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for `distinct Culture name`? So what about `es-es`?

Comment: es-es was just in there to show other cultures can exist - in this case a group of 3. Basically I have rows representing assets that could exist in multiple cultures. I dont want to have to add a bunch of entries in the culture link table again if its the same combo of cultures. So if I can find a group that already has en-gb and fr-fr I can just add that GroupID to the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are searching for `'en-gb','fr-fr'` below.

One way

```
SELECT GroupID
FROM   T
GROUP  BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT (CASE
                WHEN Culture IN ( 'en-gb', 'fr-fr' ) THEN Culture
              END) = 2
       AND COUNT(Culture) = 2
```

(Edit: Removed `DISTINCT` following confirmation that a unique constraint exists to guarantee this isn't needed)

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear; if you simply want the first group that matches your criteria, then use the following:

1. Just select the first group id that matches:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 GroupID 
   FROM myTable 
   WHERE Culture = 'en-gb' 
   ORDER BY GroupID
   ```
2. A little trickier, but following the same concept and finding the group that contains *both*:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 GroupID
   FROM
   (
       SELECT GroupID
       FROM myTable
       WHERE Culture = 'en-gb'
       INTERSECT
       SELECT GroupID
       FROM myTable
       WHERE Culture = 'fr-fr'
   ) x
   ORDER BY GroupID
   ```

---

If you instead are looking for the group that *completely* and *exclusively* matches your criteria, that is the group with no extra rows, you can simply do:

```
SELECT GroupID
FROM myTable
WHERE Culture IN (<your criteria list>)
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Culture) = <count of cultures in your criteria list>
EXCEPT
SELECT GroupID
FROM myTable
WHERE Culture NOT IN (<your criteria list>)
```

Comment: The requirement is that they must match exactly the cultures specified and no more than that.

Comment: @MartinSmith Hmm, that wasn't clear the first ten times I read the OP. I can definitely see how you could read it that way though, let me add to my answer.

Comment: (Or that's how I interpreted it anyway)

Comment: My god you guys are quick. This is the first post I have put on here and Im well impressed. Im going away to try this out.

Comment: Ok - this worked perfectly too - anyone got a view as to which is the optimal query? It could be searching 30 - 40 cultures.

Comment: Probably @MartinSmith's query is slightly better? I'm not sure the performance of EXCEPT. You can stare at the execution plans and decide though.

Comment: Both of ours could probably be improved by getting rid of the `DISTINCT` if there is a suitable unique constraint to guarantee the same culture can't be present more than once in a group.

Comment: I agree @MartinSmiths feels like it would be on first glance. I will have a look at the plans. Thanks so much for prompt answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith - yes there is the constraint - the same culture cannot appear in the same group.